# how to set oracle client library path in python when multiple oracle client version installed

Tags: linux, python-3.x, cx-oracle

i have 2 oracle client installed in linux machine. 10.2 and 12.2.
Second one i have to use for cx_oracle and older one is needed for other older implementation which i cant touch.

when i add second 12.2 oracle client library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH path and running simple oracle connection python program, it is giving me below error

***cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library is at version 10.2 but must be at version 11.2 or higher***

How can i use the newer version of client library without touching the old config?

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell script that lists the 12.2 Oracle Client library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH before other Oracle libraries, and then invokes Python.

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_12_2
python "$@"
```

Comment: I got another workaround on same concept where i used 1st python code to load the oracle_home and Ld_library os.environ['ORACLE_HOME'] = '/opt/oracle/product/12.2/client' os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/opt/oracle/product/12.2/client/lib' and then call next python code to using subprocess.call function sp.call(['python3', 'xyz.py'])