# Python Oracle - How to use 2 oracle clients

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle

I need to run a django 2.1 project in a server that have an Oracle Client version 10.

But when I try to *runserver* I get this error:
**Oracle client Library must be in version 11.2 or higher**

I did some research and the obvious solution was to update the Oracle. But I can't do that because the server runs some applications that only works with Oracle Client 10.

One thing that I tought is to run two Oracle Library Clients. I did some research, one of the answers that I found:

[how to set oracle client library path in python when multiple oracle client version installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520730/how-to-set-oracle-client-library-path-in-python-when-multiple-oracle-client-vers)

But, it's on Linux and I'm on a Windows Server 2012 R2.

How could I run 2 of these Oracle Clients?

Please, could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle client ver 11.2.0.4 should be able to connect to both 10g and 12c database.

Also check this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/224222/18697) about SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION parameter.

Comment: If @WitnessTruth's DB is 10.2, the Oracle Client could even be 12.1.  There is discussion about Oracle client-database version interoperability at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#oracle-client-and-oracle-database-interoperability